# C# - Entity Framework - Insert data with foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is the database schema :

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe (
id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
title varchar(140) not null,
preparationTime int not null,
cookingTime int not null,
difficulty varchar(25) not null,
picture varchar(140) not null,
nbStars float not null,
nbPersons int not null,
description varchar(5000) not null,
ingredientsDescription varchar(800) not null,
mailFacebook varchar(60) not null
);

ALTER TABLE Recipe
ADD Constraint preparationTimeLessThan0 CHECK(preparationTime > 0);

ALTER TABLE Recipe
ADD Constraint cookingTimeLessThan0 CHECK(cookingTime > 0);

ALTER TABLE Recipe
ADD Constraint nbStarsLessThan0 CHECK(nbStars >= 0 AND nbStars < 6);

ALTER TABLE Recipe
ADD Constraint nbPersonsLessThan1 CHECK(nbPersons > 0);

CREATE TABLE Ingredient (
id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
htmlName varchar(70) not null,
refCategory int not null,
FOREIGN KEY(refCategory) REFERENCES Category
);

CREATE TABLE IngredientRecipe (
idRecipe int not null,
idIngredient int not null,
PRIMARY KEY(idRecipe,idIngredient),
FOREIGN KEY(idRecipe) REFERENCES Recipe,
FOREIGN KEY(idIngredient) REFERENCES Ingredient
);
```

A part of my code :

```
//creation de la recette
Recipe currentRecipe = new Recipe();
currentRecipe.title = title;
currentRecipe.picture = pictureName;
currentRecipe.nbPersons = recipeNbPersons;
currentRecipe.Category = category;
currentRecipe.nbStars = quality;
currentRecipe.difficulty = difficulty;
currentRecipe.description = preparation;
currentRecipe.cookingTime = cookingTime;
currentRecipe.preparationTime = prepaTime;
currentRecipe.mailFacebook = "me@email.com";
//currentRecipe.Ingredients = ingredientRecipeList;

foreach (Ingredient ingred in ingredientRecipeList) {
        currentRecipe.Ingredients.Add(ingred);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id : " + ingred.id + " name : " + ingred.name);
}
currentRecipe.ingredientsDescription = ingredients.ToString();

//printContent(title, ingredientRecipeList);
using (Entities entitie = new Entities())
{
      entitie.Recipes.Add(currentRecipe);
      entitie.SaveChanges();                       
}
```

When I add a recipe in my database, my recipe is well recorded but I don't have the right ingredients for my recipe. However, before I dida SaveChanges, when I printed the different ingredients of the different recipes(contained in ingredientRecipeList), the ingredients were correct.

Example when I print the set of ingredients of a recipe before to save in database
     id : 6088 name : aubergine(s)
     id : 6094 name : carotte(s)
     id : 6068 name : huile d'olive
     id : 6077 name : poivre
     id : 6384 name : cumin

In my database for the IngredientRecipe table, when I print the different ingredients of a recipe, I get this. idIngredient is like an auto_increment attribute. I don't understand why :

```
 idRecipe   idIngredient
   1341        8777
   1341        8778
   1341        8779
   1341        8780
   1341        8781
```

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Comment: Where is your Entity Configuration? Were you using Code First? Database First?

Comment: In my projet(/Models/IDB.edmx). I also added an instruction to prevent circular references in IDB.context.tt

Comment: In my project(/Models/IDB.edmx). I also added an instruction to prevent circular references in IDB.context.tt. What's Code First ? Database First ? For every recipe, before to do a SaveChanges(), I printed the ingredients of every recipes and that were correct. But after executing SaveChanges(), I notice that in my database, there is a problem. It's what I explained.

Comment: Code First and Database First are two approaches to mapping your data entities to your database. Knowing how you're telling it the `Recipe`s and `Ingredient`s are related would really help in figuring out why they aren't working.